# Testing POST request throwing a KeyError in Postman

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am currently testing my POST request for the Tagging model. For this, I have tried to override the create() method. I am not so sure I have done this correctly but I tried everything I could think of. I even removed it and tried testing the POST request without overriding it.

I keep getting this error while testing with Postman:

```
KeyError at /api/tagging 'user'
```

How can I get rid of this error? What is my create() method missing?

**serializers.py**

```
class TaggingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  tag = StringRelatedField()
  resource = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
  gameround = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
  user = CustomUserSerializer(required=False, read_only=True)

  class Meta:
    model = Tagging
    fields = ('id', 'user', 'gameround', 'resource', 'tag', 'created', 'score', 'origin')

  def create(self, validated_data):
    """Create and return a new tagging"""

    tagging = Tagging(
      user=validated_data["user"],
      gameround=validated_data["gameround"],
      resource=validated_data["resource"],
      tag=validated_data["tag"],
      created=validated_data["created"],
      score=validated_data["score"],
      origin=validated_data["origin"]
    )
    tagging.save()
    return tagging

  def to_representation(self, data):
    data = super().to_representation(data)
    return data
```

If I change the create method to:

```
  def create(self, validated_data):
    """Create and return a new tagging"""

    tagging = Tagging(
      user=validated_data.get("user"),
      gameround=validated_data.get("gameround"),
      resource=validated_data.get("resource"),
      tag=validated_data.get("tag"),
      created=validated_data.get("created"),
      score=validated_data.get("score"),
      origin=validated_data.get("origin")
    )
    tagging.save()
    return tagging
```

I am getting an

```
IntegrityError: null value in column "created" of relation "app_tagging" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (15, null, 0, , null, null, null, null).
```

This is my post request:

```
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        tagging_serializer = TaggingSerializer(data=request.data)
        if tagging_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            tagging_serializer.save(tagging=request.data)
            return Response({"status": "success", "data": tagging_serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response({"status": "error", "data": tagging_serializer.errors}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

This is the JSON I am sending

```
{
        "user": null,
        "gameround": 1,
        "resource": 602,
        "tag": "RTTesttaggg",
        "created": "2022-12-12T15:19:49.031000Z",
        "score": 0,
        "origin": ""
    }
```

**models.py**

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email address', unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True, blank=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, default=timezone.now)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_uploader = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def get_username(self):
        return self.username

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.email} ({self.username})' or ''


class Resource(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False, primary_key=True)
    hash_id = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    creators = models.ManyToManyField(Creator)
    titles = models.ManyToManyField(Title)
    created_start = models.DateField(null=True)
    created_end = models.DateField(null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=512, null=True)
    institution_source = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True)
    institution = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True)
    origin = models.URLField(max_length=256, null=True)
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    media_type = models.CharField(max_length=256, default='picture')

    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.hash_id or ''

    @property
    def tags(self):
        tags = self.taggings.values('tag').annotate(count=Count('tag'))

        return tags.values('tag_id', 'tag__name', 'tag__language', 'count')


class Gameround(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    gamesession = models.ForeignKey(Gamesession, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    objects = models.Manager()

    @property
    def tags(self):
        tags = self.taggings.values('tag')

        return tags.values('tag_id', 'tag__name', 'tag__language', 'resource_id')


class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name or ''

    @property
    def tags(self):
        tags = self.tagging.values('tag')
        return tags.values('tag_id', 'tag__name', 'tag__language')


class Tagging(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    gameround = models.ForeignKey(Gameround, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='taggings')
    resource = models.ForeignKey(Resource, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='taggings')
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tagging')
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    origin = models.URLField(max_length=256, blank=True, default='')

    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.tag) or ''
```

Comment: are you sure you are sending ```user``` in body? can you show your json from postman. also one more suggestion instead of  ```validated_data["key"]```, you should use ```validated_data,get("key")``` as it ll return ```None``` instead of ```KeyError```

Comment: I have reset everything to validated_data.get("key") and updated my code with the json. Now I am getting an IntegrityError "null value in column "created" of relation "app_tagging" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (15, null, 0, , null, null, null, null)."

Comment: Update question with your models. It most probably the issue with your models where you have not set null=True

Comment: Ok I updated my Question with the models now.

Comment: The original `KeyError` was because the user field was declared with `read_only=True`. Did you intend to mark it as read only?

Comment: I took read_only=True out everywhere and am getting "{"user":["This field may not be null."],"gameround":{"non_field_errors":["Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int."]},"resource":{"non_field_errors":["Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int."]},"tag":{"non_field_errors":["Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got str."]}}"